# Php Login With Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, pdo

I am trying to make a login with ajax, I want the user to login and if the username(email) and password are correct the page should use the method .load to load the page "perfil.php", that I won't post the code since it isn't relevant.
However nothing is happening even if i type random user/password.

I just started with SESSION's and AJAX so any help would be appreciated, BTW i don't need answers talking about hashing the password at this moment.

**index**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_SESSION['login_user'])){
        header('Location: user/perfil.php');
    }
?>

<form class="form-signin" id="form-signin" method="post" action="">
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign in</h2>
<input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="true" autofocus="true">
<input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="true">
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Lembrar-me
    </label>
</div>
<button id="entrar" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="submit">Sign in</button>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
include_once '../config/db.php';
session_start();
if (isSet($_POST['email']) && isSet($_POST['password'])) {
    try {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query= "SELECT id FROM utilizador WHERE email = '$email' and pass = '$password'";

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();  
        $num=$stmt->rowCount();

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($num > 0)
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$row['id'];
            echo $row['id'];    
        }
        Database::disconnect();
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

**javascript**

```
$('#entrar').click(function()
{
    var email = $("#inputEmail").val();
    var password = $("#inputPassword").val();
    var dataString = 'email='+email+'&password='+password;
    if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "user/login.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){ $("#entrar").val('A entrar...');},
            success: function(data){
                if(data)
                {
                    showNotas();
                    $('#form-signin').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                        $("#section-1 .container").load("user/perfil.php").fadeIn(1500).delay(5000);
                        $("#section-1 span").text("Perfil");
                    });
                    $('#notas').show();
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#entrar").val('Sign in')
                    $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
return false;
});
```

**EDIT:**
Chrome dev isn't displaying any error

Comment: Have you turned error_reporting on? Are there any errors in your javascript console? Is the php script called correctly? If yes, what does it return? Also: Never EVER save passwords plain text in your database. ALWAYS encrypt/hash them. People often use the same password for multiple services.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however as i wrote in the post: " BTW i don't need answers talking about hashing the password at this moment." And no there are no error's in the console

Comment: It is just terrible style. For your question: Have you checked for errors in PHP? Does the script return what you expect? You can check it by using curl to post data or use a chrome extension like postman

Comment: I know its a terrible practice, and  update the code to that later. Im not really familiarized with cURL. Could you take another look to the post please? ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why but i changed the `$('#entrar').click(function( event )` to `function entrar()` and moved it outside the `$(document).ready(function()` and it worked.. 
Thanks everyon anyway, 
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Developer Tools may not be displayed any errors in your console, however, go along to the Network tab, click on the XHR Request (the file AJAX will ping to make the request to log a user in, I'm assuming it'll be `user/login.php`, and go to the Preview and/or Response tab and see post back what they say to us. It may well just be a PHP error, not JavaScript

Comment: I was referring to that already, either the console and the xhr tab are not displaying anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

**html** (changed checkbox, added id)

```
...
<label>
    <input id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Lembrar-me
</label>
...
```

**js**

```
$('#entrar').click(function( event )
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var email = $("#inputEmail").val();
    var password = $("#inputPassword").val();
    var rememberMe = 'unchecked';

    if ( $('#rememberMe').is(':checked') ){
        rememberMe = 'checked';
    } else {
        rememberMe = 'unchecked';
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'user/login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            email:email,
            password:password,
            rememberMe:rememberMe
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**user/login.php**

```
session_start();

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$rememberMe = $_POST['rememberMe'];

$_SESSION['test_email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['test_password'] = $password;

echo 'sessions: <br>' . $_SESSION['test_email'] . ' | ' . $_SESSION['test_password'] . ' | remember me: ' . $rememberMe;
```

**UPDATED**

add this code to the top of login.php file to reveal php errors

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);
```

Comment: Hey mate, the page just refreshs anyway

Comment: It didn't mate, still the same. I wonder if my login.php is missing something

Comment: Strangely, I tested and everything works as it should. Add ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0); to the top of login.php

Comment: Still nothing, can i contact you elsewhere?

Comment: Uploaded working code to my server. Demo: http://rubob.net/stackoverflow-test/test.php | Download sources: http://rubob.net/stackoverflow-test/stackoverflow-test.zip . You can contact me via telegram (my nickname's "aeternam").

Comment: (leave me your email and i'll send invite from telegram)

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to answer your question since we don't know what the problem is. So I just describe a systematic approach on how to solve such a situation.

- You have to test every single part of your code to determine, where the problem lies. That means: Javascript, PHP, Database.
- You should start with the PHP. Maybe first don't use data from POST but just hardcode an email & password and then see if the query against the database delivers the expected result. Or query the database but don't use data from POST.
- If PHP just returns nothing make sure you have turned on error reporting. You otherwise will not know why something isn't working. This can be done by adding error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of your PHP code, above all includes and requires.
- If this is working, try doing it with post. First submit your form without Javascript. You could use the action attribute of the form and just submit it normally. Or you use something like [`curl`](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request) or [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm). See what PHP says with error reporting on.
- Now do the same POST with your Ajax script. You could add `console.log(variable)` statements and watch in the console if anything goes wrong.

**Oh, and while writing all this I spotted a missing `{` in your code. This could be the problem... ;)**

```
<?php
include_once '../config/db.php';
session_start();
if (isSet($_POST['email']) && isSet($_POST['password'])) {
    try {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query= "SELECT id FROM utilizador WHERE email = '$email' and pass = '$password'";

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();  
        $num=$stmt->rowCount();

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($num > 0) { // THIS WAS MISSING
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$row['id'];
            echo $row['id'];    
        }
        Database::disconnect();
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}
?>
```